# How does "huios" compare with "teknon" in Luke 15:30-31?

Tags: luke

**Luke 15:30-31**

> "But when this son[**huios**] of yours came, who has devoured your property with prostitutes, you killed the fattened calf for him!" *31* And he said to him, "Son,[**teknon**] you are always with me, and all that is mine is yours." ESV. My brackets and emphasis.

The elder brother speaking to his father says, "this son[huios] of yours". But in his reply the father does not repeat the word that has just been said to him. Instead he says, "Son[teknon]  you are always with me".

How do these two Greek words compare in this story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the touching parable of the so-called ‘Prodigal Son’, we find a sequence of two Greek terms (singular and/or plural) that the vast majority of Bible translations render merely as ‘son/sons’:

- *υιους*, ‘sons’ (15:11); *υιος*, ‘son’ (15:13, 19, 21 [twice], 24, 25, 30) = 8 times
- *τεκνον*, ‘son’ (15:31) = only once.

**A pivotal and evident concept is that Luke – utilizing once *τεκνον* among a number of terms *υιους*/*υιος*, in the same context – did want to emphasize a semantic difference inside the economy of the parable**.

Dottard has yet explained that “while the two words for ‘son’ are very similar, ‘teknon’ has greater overtones of ‘child’ than the other and is more affectionate”. Nevertheless, he did not back his (though correct) statement with substantial evidence drawn from reference texts.

Furthermore, an accurate analysis of the context (that includes the whole of chapter 15) makes us clear that the father’s answer to his older son was not simply – as Dottard says - “an attempt at reconciliation by trying to calm an angry son”. Really, behind his talk was concealed a profound lesson based on the true relationship between those two men (father & older son).

Let us start with the first point: the semantic difference between *υιος* and *τεκνον* (or, also the derivative term *τεκνιον* [diminutive of *τεκνον*]). The bold emphasis is mine.

First of all, in all the Homeric works this term is **used as a gentle word addressed to adult ones** (see, for a couple of examples, *Iliad* 22, 84; *Odyssey* 2, 363).

> *τεκνον* denotes the child son or daughter, […] in most of its uses it appears […] in the context of **expressing affection and emotion**. The term appears in the context of *supplication* [in *Hecuba* 277 Hecuba supplicates Ulysses not to snatch Polyxena from her (…); in *Electra 1165* Clytemnestra supplicates Orestes not to kill her (…)], in the context of Agamemnon’s paternal emotion in light of his daughter’s arrival [Euripides, *Iphigenia at Aulis*, 643] and in the scenes of farewell which take place between the children and their mother who freely chooses to sacrify herself instead of her husband [Euripides, *Alcestis*, 270-3]. […] *Τεκνον* is often used interchangeably with *παις* **for singling out the paternal or maternal affection**. Oedipus addresses Antigone as *τεκνον* (Phen., 1719) and in this way he **expresses his affection** toward her. […] Aethra similarly addresses Theseus in the beginning as παι and then as *τεκνον* (*Phen*., 103). *Τεκνον* and *παις* are juxtaposed in *Hec*. 171 […]. This juxtaposition permits to Hecuba to express her feeling of helplessness as she must announce the achaean army’s decision to her daughters. […] As *παις*, *τεκνον* is used by a relative **for the purposes of expressing his affection toward person**. In *Hec*. 427, Ioloas addresses Heracles’ children [so][…]. In this passage, the term is interchangeable with *παιδες* (439 […]) <sup>1</sup>

> *τεκνιον* […] *It is a term of great affection and tenderness*. See Joh 13:33; Gal 4:19, 1 Joh 2:1 […] ‘Dear children’, Campbell’s *Prelim. Dissert*, p. 615.  <sup>2</sup>  <sup>3</sup>

The special affection Paul felt for Timothy was expressed through the use of *τεκνον*, at least on two occasions (see, please 1 Timothy 1:18; Philippians 2:22). In the latter passage Paul use also the expression “he has served in gospel with me [*συν εμοι*]”.

Returning to the parable we may safely conclude that the father’s talk was not addressed merely to ‘sugar the pill’ to his older son but it had a more profound significance.

The aim of the father of the parable (toward his older son) was to reassure him of his love, and that this son had the same moral and spiritual stature as himself. The complaint of the older son was not related to a fatherly prohibition to pick up (from the family herd) a single kid to be roasted in the company of his friends. Note the phraseology of the older son, “to me you never once gave a kid…”. The older son was not accusing his father of an imaginary meanness, but that his father never once organized a banquet to fête him despite his (son’s) blamelessness!

And at this dramatic point, his father reveals his full feelings toward his older son.

1. He called his son τεκνον, not merely υιος, with all the emotive implications we have outlined above.
2. Acknowledging the blamelessness of the son, he said: “You have always been with me [*μετ’εμου*]…” Differently from the (above mentioned) expression used by Paul about Timothy (in Philippians 2:22 [*συν εμοι*]) here, the parable’s father uses the Greek expression *μετ’εμου*, **which put the emphasis on the agreement (moral and spiritual) between him and his older son**.

Indeed, this expression can be translated as “You have always been in accord with me…” Compare, please, *μετα καιρου*, ‘according the appropriate [or, ‘fixed’] time’ (Tucydides 6, 85); *μετα του νομου και τουδικαιου… διακινδυνευειν*, ‘to risk in accord with law and justice’ (Plato, *Apology of Socrates*, 32c); or, again, μετα *Βοιωτων εμαχοντο*, ‘the Beotes battled together with’ (Homerus, *Iliad*, XIII, 700), and so on.

3. With the expression “all the things that are mine are yours”, the father reassures that yet in that time (with the father alive) he considered his older son (respecting the father’s estates) as being in joint ownership with him.

Indeed, Howard Marshall, in *The New International Greek Testament Commentary* (NIGTC) – *The Gospel of Luke* observes: “The father addresses the son affectionately (*τέκνον*) and assures him that he is constantly (*πάντοτε*, contrast *οὐδέποτε*, v. 29) with him, and that **all his father now possesses is his**. **The saying must be interpreted to mean that legally the son will inherit the farm, since it has already been promised to him**. If the son has not already enjoyed the fruits of it, it is because he has not asked rather than because the father was unwilling to give it.”

4. With the expression “but we had to enjoy ourselves and rejoice, because…”, the father admitted that his decision to prepare a banquet for his younger son sprang from an unusual circumstance, as the father had said ‘Normally, we do not do so (but)…’. This concept is confirmed by the fact that he equalized the return of his younger son to a resurrection.

If we imagine attending to the resurrection of our friend, do we act as usual? For example, in Luke 8:56, speaking about the mental and emotive condition of the resurrected girl’s parents (Jairus and his wife), the evangelist uses the Greek verbal form *εξεστησαν*, ‘to be out(side) of their mind’, or alike (by the way, the term *ecstasy* comes just from this Greek term). Surely, we also will lose our self-possession, in this instance.

So, the parable’s father according to an unusual circumstance (the spiritual resurrection of his younger son) reacted with an unusual behaviour, namely, preparing a huge banquet for the return of his repented son, along with the spiritual, and familiar reassessment of the status of that previous sinner (compare with Luke 15:4-7, that is placed inside the parable’s context, and illustrates – in this case, too – an unusual behaviour of the shepherd).

Approaching to conclude the argument, we may safely affirm that the best readings of this passage have to include the different nuance of *τεκνον* with respect to *υιος*.

But, could it be enough – in an English translation of the term *τεκνον* – to add, for example, a possessive particle, as ‘my’, in order to try to copy the semantic field of *τεκνον*? Besides, translations such as ISV, NAB, NIV, *God’s Word*, and *The Jerusalem Bible* (English edition), render *τεκνον* (in Luke 15:31) just as ‘My son’. So, could it be that this is the best mode to translate this term? Hardly. In fact, in 1 John 2:1, we find exactly the term at issue followed by a possessive pronoun, *τεκνια* *μου* (as yet in *Iliad* 1,414, *τεκνον εμον*).

Correctly, the following Bible versions translate *τεκνον* in a manner that can possibly (by the reader) catch the endearment’s nuance of that term: ‘dear son’, according to *New Living Translation*, Weymouth NT.

---

References

1. Hélène Perdicoyianni-Paléologu, *The Vocabulary of Kinship in Euripides* (article) [inside *Rivista di Cultura Classica e Medioevale*, no. 2 (Jul-Dec 2002)], pages 257-8.
2. John Parkhurst, *A Greek and English Lexicon to the New Testament* […] on *Τεκνιον*.
3. For *τεκνιον* as diminutive of *τεκνον* see Robert Beeks, *Etymological Dictionary of Greek*, volume 1, p. 1460 (on *τεκνον*).

Answer (score 2):

The meanings of τέκνον (teknon) and υἱός (huios) overlap a lot!  They are sometimes used as direct synonyms in both the literal and spiritual sense.

However, their similarity is deliberately contrasted in Luke 15:30 & 31 as the OP implies:

- V30 - "this son of yours" is a way of the elder brother distancing himself from his brother
- V31 - "teknon" might most helpfully be translated (in this instance) as "child" - a term of affection.

Thus, the father's speech is an attempt at reconciliation by trying to calm an angry son with a term of endearment.  That is, while the two words for "son" are very similar, "teknon" has greater overtones of "child" than the other and is more affectionate.